# Debugging Postgres 9.3 Triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, debugging

Right now I have a trigger in my database that is giving me some issues. I've set up this line so I can check what is being fetched from a query

```
RAISE NOTICE 'hstore_key = %',hstore_key;
```

as well I have postgres configured as so for logging

```
log_destination = 'stderr'

logging_collector = on

log_directory = '/var/log/pg_log'written,

client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = notice
log_min_error_statement = notice
```

But when I check my log at /var/log/pg_log I don't see any thing regarding my notice, using the command

```
/hstore_key =
```

in vim to search for the string that the notice should have put out. I have also tried to place a test notice at the start of the trigger (the trigger executes successfully, it just does not give me the results I'm looking for), the notice I placed at the top of the trigger was

```
RAISE NOTICE 'beginning of proto trigger';
```

And it does not display in the log either. Is there a configuration setting I missed enabling in my postgresql.conf?

Comment: One possibility: you have more than one PostgreSQL instance and you're looking at the wrong logs. `SHOW config_file;` to make sure the `postgresql.conf` is the right one for the server you're actually connecting to.

Comment: I just checked the return of SHOW config_file; and it returns the path to the configuration file I had edited.